# EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter, sigabrt

Can anyone assist with how to interpret this crash log? Users report that in some point of app usage (after taking photo, sending photo to API when returning to the main screen) screen start to flicker. Users cant't tap anything, then app crashes on iOS, on Android app stays in that state. The bug is irregular and I can't reproduce it in a debug and production environment which makes it even harder to resolve. I have been able to symbolicate the report but do not know how to interpret the cause of the problem.

Crash report:

```
Incident Identifier: 
CrashReporter Key:   
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,8
Process:         Runner [57814]
Path:            /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/C22E07A7-63F8-4626-8E65-739279E7D8A8/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:      
Version:         
Code Type:       ARM-64
Parent Process:  ? [1]

Date/Time:       2022-01-07 13:12:51.000 +0100
OS Version:      iOS 15.1 (19B74)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000 at 0x00000001b7fc8964
Crashed Thread:  4

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2b9c mach_msg + 76
2   (null) 0xab03f901810ef688 0x0 + 12322966790271334024
3   (null) 0x646e4781810f397c 0x0 + 7236800272772577660
4   (null) 0x9613f701811073b8 0x0 + 10814258716079059896
5   (null) 0x547511819ca9738c 0x0 + 6085789719837897612
6   (null) 0xd93b158183aa76a8 0x0 + 15653128575860242088
7   (null) 0xf82c0901838267f4 0x0 + 17882678122487375860
8   (null) 0x5f313a0102980f70 0x0 + 6859327483474874224
9   (null) 0x0000000103455a24 0x0 + 4349844004

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc5b44 poll + 8
1   Runner                          0x0000000102db73ec absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParsedFloat absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParseFloat<16>(char const*, char const*, absl::lts_2020_02_25::chars_format) + 466784
2   Runner                          0x0000000102db9188 absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParsedFloat absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParseFloat<16>(char const*, char const*, absl::lts_2020_02_25::chars_format) + 474364
3   Runner                          0x0000000102dac850 absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParsedFloat absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParseFloat<16>(char const*, char const*, absl::lts_2020_02_25::chars_format) + 422852
4   Runner                          0x0000000102d79a2c absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParsedFloat absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParseFloat<16>(char const*, char const*, absl::lts_2020_02_25::chars_format) + 214432
5   Runner                          0x0000000102a18b68 GRPC_SHADOW_sdallocx + 431968
6   Runner                          0x0000000102af5a18 GRPC_SHADOW_sdallocx + 1336848
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180df3660 0x180def000 + 18016
8   (null) 0x0756478180dfade4 0x0 + 528688627801107940
9   (null) 0x1c67f88180dfb958 0x0 + 2046877790759795032
10  (null) 0x93046d0180e061a8 0x0 + 10593712076706832808
11  (null) 0xe76f2201f14220f4 0x0 + 16676585336914190580

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2b9c mach_msg + 76
2   (null) 0xcb060881810ef688 0x0 + 14629389791868679816
3   (null) 0x09366901810f397c 0x0 + 663833450264869244
4   (null) 0x6a64c081811073b8 0x0 + 7666464128140080056
5   (null) 0xb74bd40182922354 0x0 + 13207883435144782676
6   (null) 0xad602a8182963c28 0x0 + 12493032102055787560
7   (null) 0x497df58183a208a4 0x0 + 5295658673465591972
8   (null) 0xf31e3a818297236c 0x0 + 17518503928433943404
9   (null) 0xe41ddf81f14229a4 0x0 + 16437539964163598756

Thread 3 name:  io.flutter.1.ui
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2b9c mach_msg + 76
2   (null) 0xa62c9701810ef688 0x0 + 11974111541987309192
3   (null) 0x80072d01810f397c 0x0 + 9225391846175226236
4   (null) 0xd2094201811073b8 0x0 + 15134700596983002040
5   (null) 0xe54c1701050d8f74 0x0 + 16522606426062688116
6   Flutter                         0x00000001050d8788 0x104de8000 + 3082120
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 4 name:  io.flutter.1.raster
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc8964 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1428378 pthread_kill + 268
2   (null) 0x7c7ceb818bfbef50 0x0 + 8970303499447037776
3   (null) 0xbd4513819b536390 0x0 + 13638328493939057552
4   (null) 0x4411a381ca5adba8 0x0 + 4904881247024241576
5   (null) 0xc32d70019b48c6b0 0x0 + 14064020363550443184
6   (null) 0x36653481ca5af824 0x0 + 3919596782746269732
7   (null) 0x1e19c681f28844ac 0x0 + 2168982956977702060
8   (null) 0xda67ed01f27d4d5c 0x0 + 15737808015488535900
9   (null) 0xd60eb2010506fde8 0x0 + 15424461491239583208
10  Flutter                         0x00000001050764a8 0x104de8000 + 2679976
11  Flutter                         0x0000000105073584 0x104de8000 + 2667908
12  Flutter                         0x0000000104f84fd0 0x104de8000 + 1691600
13  Flutter                         0x0000000104f7a0c4 0x104de8000 + 1646788
14  Flutter                         0x0000000104f7a4b0 0x104de8000 + 1647792
15  Flutter                         0x0000000104e40c34 0x104de8000 + 363572
16  Flutter                         0x00000001052de3f0 0x104de8000 + 5202928
17  Flutter                         0x00000001051f1fc4 0x104de8000 + 4235204
18  Flutter                         0x0000000105129d3c 0x104de8000 + 3415356
19  Flutter                         0x0000000105131bd4 0x104de8000 + 3447764
20  Flutter                         0x00000001050d6068 0x104de8000 + 3072104
21  Flutter                         0x00000001050d9098 0x104de8000 + 3084440
22  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181196268 0x1810e8000 + 713320
23  (null) 0x2f161a018111ac40 0x0 + 3392927963032955968
24  (null) 0x747b44818111543c 0x0 + 8393377653541917756
25  (null) 0x42689181810f3c58 0x0 + 4785234589483220056
26  (null) 0xb114a101811073b8 0x0 + 12760000672079836088
27  (null) 0xb60ded01050d8f74 0x0 + 13118401878235647860
28  Flutter                         0x00000001050d8788 0x104de8000 + 3082120
29  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 5 name:  io.flutter.1.io
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2b9c mach_msg + 76
2   (null) 0x4349f281810ef688 0x0 + 4848673111870994056
3   (null) 0x83524d01810f397c 0x0 + 9462710435914398076
4   (null) 0x3162c501811073b8 0x0 + 3558623265827091384
5   (null) 0xd03d2c01050d8f74 0x0 + 15005197916359724916
6   Flutter                         0x00000001050d8788 0x104de8000 + 3082120
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 6 name:  io.worker.1
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2f90 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1429254 0x1f1421000 + 33364
2   (null) 0x420e0b819988fddc 0x0 + 4759754507431771612
3   (null) 0x52195701050d3b60 0x0 + 5915855247419194208
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 7 name:  io.worker.2
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2f90 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1429254 0x1f1421000 + 33364
2   (null) 0xc32f8f019988fddc 0x0 + 14064617398334979548
3   (null) 0xb95a4a81050d3b60 0x0 + 13356069562916617056
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 8 name:  io.worker.3
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2f90 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1429254 0x1f1421000 + 33364
2   (null) 0x4a1b87819988fddc 0x0 + 5340010773874277852
3   (null) 0x160e0881050d3b60 0x0 + 1589217068736920416
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 9 name:  io.worker.4
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2f90 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1429254 0x1f1421000 + 33364
2   (null) 0xc44084019988fddc 0x0 + 14141447972349083100
3   (null) 0xe3215681050d3b60 0x0 + 16366457632976616288
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 10 name:  io.worker.5
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2f90 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1429254 0x1f1421000 + 33364
2   (null) 0x553c64019988fddc 0x0 + 6141893949860150748
3   (null) 0x87488881050d3b60 0x0 + 9748191481160350560
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 11 name:  io.worker.6
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2f90 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1429254 0x1f1421000 + 33364
2   (null) 0xd717a6019988fddc 0x0 + 15499039168419921372
3   (null) 0x75221701050d3b60 0x0 + 8440333944792890208
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 12 name:  dart:io EventHandler
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc3e7c kevent + 8
1   Flutter                         0x000000010522348c 0x104de8000 + 4437132
2   Flutter                         0x0000000105250cc4 0x104de8000 + 4623556
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 13 name:  JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2f90 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1429254 0x1f1421000 + 33364
2   (null) 0x481df6819988fddc 0x0 + 5196580581542526428
3   (null) 0x265a40818d2281d4 0x0 + 2763592246508028372
4   (null) 0xe210ab818d22c9a4 0x0 + 16289708425106082212
5   (null) 0x346795818d22c544 0x0 + 3776151196224636228
6   (null) 0x79051e018d22da00 0x0 + 8720409245484505600
7   (null) 0xe1634d81f14229a4 0x0 + 16240909901721905572

Thread 14 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2b9c mach_msg + 76
2   (null) 0xd14b0c01810ef688 0x0 + 15081160977779979912
3   (null) 0x2c4bba81810f397c 0x0 + 3191849826300934524
4   (null) 0x48229381811073b8 0x0 + 5197879104364377016
5   (null) 0x611e888181b7b6a0 0x0 + 6998180960788788896
6   (null) 0xbf1faf018297236c 0x0 + 13771918606543037292
7   (null) 0x030f3801f14229a4 0x0 + 220456487758211492

Thread 15 name:  com.google.firebase.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2b9c mach_msg + 76
2   (null) 0x343afd8103b9d140 0x0 + 3763599169176588608
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2ae4 __semwait_signal + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000018bfa3f00 nanosleep + 216
2   (null) 0xba373c818bfb7f3c 0x0 + 13418260141870645052
3   (null) 0x09124d0103679fe4 0x0 + 653669562669572068
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 17 name:  KSCrash Exception Handler (Secondary)
Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2b9c mach_msg + 76
2   (null) 0xf821e501b7fce230 0x0 + 17879823791182111280
3   (null) 0xa32cdf0103684f64 0x0 + 11758017922602651492
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 18 name:  KSCrash Exception Handler (Primary)
Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2b9c mach_msg + 76
2   (null) 0xa373b50103684f90 0x0 + 11777956466460741520
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 19 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2b9c mach_msg + 76
2   (null) 0xbc452f01810ef688 0x0 + 13566301136030201480
3   (null) 0x45294701810f397c 0x0 + 4983592534447962492
4   (null) 0x54154d81811073b8 0x0 + 6058834092308329400
5   (null) 0x663c50018a49b308 0x0 + 7366851058016563976
6   (null) 0x6d6102018a4a4d64 0x0 + 7881583028513426788
7   (null) 0xe81bf181f14229a4 0x0 + 16725227181571189156

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2f90 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1429254 0x1f1421000 + 33364
2   (null) 0x705a948102e0ec18 0x0 + 8095946561971874840
3   Runner                          0x0000000102dba424 absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParsedFloat absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParseFloat<16>(char const*, char const*, absl::lts_2020_02_25::chars_format) + 479128
4   Runner                          0x0000000102e14e14 absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParsedFloat absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParseFloat<16>(char const*, char const*, absl::lts_2020_02_25::chars_format) + 850312
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2f90 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1429254 0x1f1421000 + 33364
2   (null) 0xca6f608102e0ec18 0x0 + 14586983825291668504
3   Runner                          0x0000000102dba424 absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParsedFloat absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParseFloat<16>(char const*, char const*, absl::lts_2020_02_25::chars_format) + 479128
4   Runner                          0x0000000102e14e14 absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParsedFloat absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParseFloat<16>(char const*, char const*, absl::lts_2020_02_25::chars_format) + 850312
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2f90 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1429254 0x1f1421000 + 33364
2   (null) 0xc929ff0102e0ec08 0x0 + 14495397255476997128
3   Runner                          0x0000000102e176c8 absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParsedFloat absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParseFloat<16>(char const*, char const*, absl::lts_2020_02_25::chars_format) + 860732
4   Runner                          0x0000000102e14e14 absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParsedFloat absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParseFloat<16>(char const*, char const*, absl::lts_2020_02_25::chars_format) + 850312
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2f90 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1429254 0x1f1421000 + 33364
2   (null) 0x6143d90102e0ec18 0x0 + 7008684043485113368
3   Runner                          0x0000000102e176c8 absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParsedFloat absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParseFloat<16>(char const*, char const*, absl::lts_2020_02_25::chars_format) + 860732
4   Runner                          0x0000000102e14e14 absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParsedFloat absl::lts_2020_02_25::strings_internal::ParseFloat<16>(char const*, char const*, absl::lts_2020_02_25::chars_format) + 850312
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 24:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2b2c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1422140 _pthread_wqthread + 364

Thread 25:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2b2c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1422140 _pthread_wqthread + 364

Thread 26:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2b2c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1422140 _pthread_wqthread + 364

Thread 27:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1421e8c 0x1f1421000 + 3724

Thread 28 name:  com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
Thread 28:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2504 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2b9c mach_msg + 76
2   (null) 0x897e9b01810ef688 0x0 + 9907526661024183944
3   (null) 0x235c1e01810f397c 0x0 + 2547944480993917308
4   (null) 0x15552c01811073b8 0x0 + 1537183232788820920
5   (null) 0xc7230c8181187a78 0x0 + 14349326588088711800
6   (null) 0x9a7a4d018e0e7544 0x0 + 11131294098073220420
7   (null) 0x58322401f14229a4 0x0 + 6355181614934403492

Thread 29:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2b2c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1422140 _pthread_wqthread + 364

Thread 30:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1421e8c 0x1f1421000 + 3724

Thread 31:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1421e8c 0x1f1421000 + 3724

Thread 32:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2b2c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1422140 _pthread_wqthread + 364

Thread 33:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2f90 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1429280 0x1f1421000 + 33408
2   (null) 0x194b370105381374 0x0 + 1822610951723553652
3   Flutter                         0x00000001053c7214 0x104de8000 + 6156820
4   Flutter                         0x0000000105380c9c 0x104de8000 + 5868700
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 34:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001b7fc2f90 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f1429280 0x1f1421000 + 33408
2   (null) 0xaf50f78105381374 0x0 + 12632869088284644212
3   Flutter                         0x00000001053c7214 0x104de8000 + 6156820
4   Flutter                         0x0000000105380c9c 0x104de8000 + 5868700
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001f14229a4 _pthread_start + 148

Thread 4 crashed with ARM-64 Thread State:
  cpsr: 0x0000000040000000     fp: 0x000000016d966750     lr: 0x00000001f1428378     pc: 0x00000001b7fc8964 
    sp: 0x000000016d966730     x0: 0x0000000000000000     x1: 0x0000000000000000    x10: 0x0000000150040060 
   x11: 0x0000000000000001    x12: 0x000000000000001f    x13: 0x00000000c4a0c852    x14: 0x00000000c4c0d000 
   x15: 0x000000000000d000    x16: 0x0000000000000148    x17: 0x000000016d96b000    x18: 0x0000000000000000 
   x19: 0x0000000000000006     x2: 0x0000000000000000    x20: 0x0000000000005803    x21: 0x000000016d96b0e0 
   x22: 0x0000000000000000    x23: 0x00000001d836e000    x24: 0x0000000000000000    x25: 0x00000001546323a0 
   x26: 0x00000001cb5e2d7e    x27: 0x0000000280d4fcf0    x28: 0x0000000155236338    x29: 0x000000016d966750 
    x3: 0x0000000000000000     x4: 0x0000000000000180     x5: 0x00000001545a7ee0     x6: 0x000000000000001c 
    x7: 0xffffffff00038300     x8: 0xf6cd632bb96c471b     x9: 0xf6cd632ad4faf71b
```

Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 11.5.1 20G80 darwin-arm, locale pl-PL)
    • Flutter version 2.5.3 at /Users/user/fvm/versions/2.5.3
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 18116933e7 (3 months ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
    • Engine revision d3ea636dc5
    • Dart version 2.14.4

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk
    ✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for more details.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 13.2.1, Build version 13C100
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2
```

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Did you get any more information about this crash? Anything would help.